# Using R as a game simulator

Tags: r, for-loop, simulation

I am trying to simulate a simple game where you spin a spinner, labeled 1-5, and then progress on until you pass the finish line (spot 50). I am a bit new to R and have been working on this for a while searching for answers. When I run the code below, it doesn't add the numbers in sequence, it returns a list of my 50 random spins and their value. How do I get this to add the spins on top of each other, then stop once => 50?

```
SpacesOnSpinner<-(seq(1,5,by=1))
N<-50
L1<-integer(N)

for (i in 1:N){
takeaspin<-sample(SpacesOnSpinner,1,replace=TRUE)
L1[i]<-L1[i]+takeaspin
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a while statement and a variable *total* for keeping track of the sum:

```
total <- 0
while(total <= 50){
   takeaspin<-sample(SpacesOnSpinner,1,replace=TRUE)
   total <- takeaspin + total
} 

print (total)
```

Comment: +1 because this is how the original should have been implemented for what they were after.

Comment: This does implement what I need in a simple way, thank you. This will actually be what I use because of what this code will ultimately do (see comment above).

Answer (score 4):

This is a good use-case for `replicate`. I'm not sure if you have to use a `for` loop, but you could do this instead (`replicate` is a loop too):

```
SpacesOnSpinner<-(seq(1,5,by=1))
N<-10
cumsum( replicate( N , sample(SpacesOnSpinner,1,replace=TRUE) ) )
#[1]  5 10 14 19 22 25 27 29 30 33
```

However, since you have a condition which you want to `break` on, perhaps the other answer with a `while` condition is exactly what you need in this case (people will tell you they are bad in R, but they have their uses). Using this method, you can see how many spins it took you to get past 50 by a simple subset afterwards (but you will not know in advance how many spins it will take, but at *most* it will be 50!):

```
N<-50
x <- cumsum( replicate( N , sample(5,1) ) )

# Value of accumulator at each round until <= 50
x[ x < 50 ]
#[1]  5  6  7  8 12 16 21 24 25 29 33 34 36 38 39 41 42 44 45 49

# Number of spins before total <= 50
length(x[x < 50])
[1] 20
```

Comment: Or you can simply use `sample(5, 1)` within your `replicate` call.

Comment: @VictorK. sure, obviously! I was copying the elements of the OPs post so they can see how it fits together. I edited the last call accordingly to show how it can be simplified.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed. The for loop was in there because this is going to turn into a simulation of this being a 2-person game, then finding the probability of 1 person being in the lead for the entire game.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another interesting way to simulate your game, using a recursive function.

```
spin <- function(outcomes = 1:5, start = 0L, end = 50L)
   if (start <= end)
      c(got <- sample(outcomes, 1), Recall(outcomes, start + got, end))

spin()
# [1] 5 4 4 5 1 5 3 2 3 4 4 1 5 4 3
```

Although elegant, it won't be as fast as an improved version of @Simon's solution that makes a single call to `sample`, as suggested by @Viktor:

```
spin <- function(outcomes = 1:5, end = 50L) {
   max.spins <- ceiling(end / min(outcomes))
   x <- sample(outcomes, max.spins, replace = TRUE)
   head(x, match(TRUE, cumsum(x) >= end))
}

spin()
# [1] 3 5 2 3 5 2 2 5 1 2 1 5 5 5 2 4
```

For your ultimate goal (*find the probability of one person being in the lead for the entire game*), it is debatable whether `while` will be more efficient or not: a while loop is certainly slower, but you may benefit from the possibility of exiting early as the lead switches from one player to the other. Both approaches are worth testing.